# Create path from string in function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to pass a string to a path, it works if I don't have quotation marks around the path i.e. like:

```
C:\Users\David\Documents\Testing\$FolderName
```

But what if I want to have the quotation marks as bellow? Is there a way to avoid the error?

```
function CreateFolder {

 param([string]$FolderName)

 New-Item 'C:\Users\David\Documents\Testing\' + $FolderName -ItemType Directory
}


CreateFolder  'TestingSub'
```

I get this error:

```
New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to evaluate the expression before `New-Item` is called:

```
function CreateFolder {

 param([string]$FolderName)
 New-Item ('C:\Users\David\Documents\Testing\' + $FolderName) -ItemType Directory
}
```

You could also use double quotes for expansion:

```
function CreateFolder {

 param([string]$FolderName)
 New-Item "C:\Users\David\Documents\Testing\$FolderName" -ItemType Directory
}
```

or you could use `Join-Path`:

```
function CreateFolder {

 param([string]$FolderName)
 New-Item (Join-Path -Path 'C:\Users\David\Documents\Testing\' -ChildPath $FolderName) -ItemType Directory
}
```